# Which module should I use to visualize my Google Analytics Data using the Google Charts engine?

Tags: 7, google-analytics, charts

I would like to import Google Analytics data of my site into my site, so that I can visualize them with the (interactive) [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) API.

Which module(s) should I use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that [Google Analytics Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) is the solution for this, no? Those "reports" do include charts also (not just tabular data).

If you rather want to create some charts yourself, consider the [Comparison of Charting Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) as a possible place to do start from, to find the module that best fits your needs. Possible alternatives that might work for this specific question are the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/node/2370811) module, or the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753) module, though there are other alternatives in that comparison that might be a better fit for this case.

The **license** that comes with the related charting library (engine) in each of these modules, should be considered also. It is one of the (important?) selection criteria for deciding on the module to go for. 'Possible privacy concerns' or 'Yes or no support for saving charts in PDFs' is another typical item to consider.

Disclosure: I'm the author of the comparison and modules [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/node/2370811) and [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753),
 I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 2):

I think I found this solution on those 3 articles:
http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/create-ultimate-google-analytics-dashboard-drupal-part-1
http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/create-ultimate-google-analytics-dashboard-drupal-part-2
http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/comment/257249

i hope this helps someone.